# "There is a picture of myself on the wall." Can a reflexive pronoun be used without an antecedent like this?

Tags: pronouns, syntactic-analysis, reflexives, antecedents

I need an answer for a question that has been bugging me for a while. So, I understand that reflexive pronouns needs to have a subject to refer to, or to be the reflection of. Then lately I've come across a sentence using a reflexive pronoun which was grammatically correct, but with the absence of the antecedent. So can a reflexive pronoun be used without an antecedent like this?

> There is a picture of myself on the wall.

Comment: I think that it should be "There is a picture of me on the wall", but I'm not sure. Using *myself* when you should use *me* is a common error.

Comment: You should indicate the source of the sentence if you can.

Comment: https://books.google.com.sa/books?id=arOAAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA59&lpg=PA59&dq=there+is+a+picture+of+myself+antecedent&source=bl&ots=2NIpaPJT7F&sig=R2dp1ooofEIyaIlcpicC0IHo2RA&hl=ar&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjR5J6mh7bPAhXBaRQKHUitC_4Q6AEINTAD#v=snippet&q=myself%20antecedent&f=false

Comment: Glancing at your link, the course materials in it seem to be showing commonly-made mistakes as correct English. As counter-examples, they would be wonderful. "This is what the British do - learn to do better" (and I would fully approve of such an attitude).

Comment: @tchrist: it's not a duplicate. "Herself" in "I gave Susie a picture of herself" has an antecedent "Susie" while "myself" in this example does not have any antecedent.

Comment: @sumelic Ok then.

Comment: @tchrist: Yeah, I think it being a picture noun might be part of the answer, I just think it's a different enough situation that it's not clear without some kind of additional explanation

Answer (score 3):

There are many uses for the word *myself*, and to treat it as *only* a reflexive pronoun is too prescriptive — so prescriptive, in fact, that it would be wrong. The use you give is indeed accepted as correct English, but for a rather tricky reason.

> Nonetheless, use of one-word myself to stand in for two-word my self is established and generally accepted: "You seem like a better version of myself" would not normally be objected to, and "I just want to be myself" is perfectly fine.
>
> [(From Slate.com)](http://www.slate.com/blogs/lexicon_valley/2014/01/17/myself_when_is_it_okay_to_use_the_reflexive_pronoun_in_a_sentence.html)

The first example that they give is exactly the use you're asking about. It's where *myself* means what it literally describes, *my self*. Suppose you were going to say *my friend* instead of *myself*. That would make sense, wouldn't it?

> There is a picture of my friend on the wall.
>
> There is a picture of myself on the wall. **same logic**

The word is simply being used in a different function than a reflexive pronoun. It's more like a contraction of the two word phrase *my self*. So it is indeed correct. The [Slate.com](http://www.slate.com/blogs/lexicon_valley/2014/01/17/myself_when_is_it_okay_to_use_the_reflexive_pronoun_in_a_sentence.html) article gives a lot of examples of both correct and incorrect usage.

Answer (score -1):

[This](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/pronouns/reflexive-pronouns) is a good, authoritative explanation of the use of reflexive pronouns.

As you can see by following the link reflexive pronouns are used when the subject and object of the verb are the same. For example "I cut myself with a knife"; "They locked themselves out of their house" and so on.

In the sentence quoted the **subject** of the sentence is "there" and there isn't a object since the verb "to be" does not take an object. The word "myself" is being used as part of an adjectival phrase which describes the picture and, as it is a phrase and not a clause, has neither subject nor object so the use of the reflexive pronoun is incorrect.

This means that the sentence is *not* grammatically correct. The correct word is "me" as @MickSharp said in his comment.

Comment: Sorry, I had to -1 your post because that BC webpage is not good!

Answer (score -1):

Evidently, the answer is "yes".  You've given a citation where a reflexive is used with no apparent antecedent, so obviously it can be used this way.  It *has* been used this way, in your example.

Perhaps it's clear that I am puzzled by the question. And I am even more puzzled when I see some people answering No to your question.  It's paradoxical to claim  that something you've just witnessed happen can't happen.

Comment: This isn't an answer about  the English language, it's simply a quibble about the logic of the question.